# In Typescript, how can I map the keys of an interface into an array of specific strings?

Tags: typescript, object, interface

I get data from the server in the form of rows and columns.
I want to generate a mapping of column header titles to the column header index.

For example, I want `{firstName: 0, lastName: 1}` in case the order later changes.

The thing I'd like to do is get Typescript to know what types to expect, but I can't get it to.

**For example, it doesn't know that `firstName` is a valid property of `columnHeaderIndices`**

```
interface TheData {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
}

const columnHeaders = data.rows[0];
const columnHeaderIndices = columnHeaders.map((i, j) => ({[i]: j}));

const firstNameColumnIndex = columnHeaderIndices.firstName;  // No type information here!

let firstNameOfFirstDataRow = data.rows[1][firstNameColumnIndex]
```

How can I get typescript to let me map the keys of an interface into an array of specific strings ?

[Here's a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/PTAEBMEMBdNBjA9gWwKYGdQDMBOLTqo4BuRAUEgHbrQQxwC8oA3maO3gO7oBcoA2m3bD%20oAERYAljhoA5SGjEAacQBtIchajEBdJUOEDxAKUTaVYgEKrEnXfsPtRYgLKSA1ufEAVHB%202gOgZBAL5kZJKU0ERYkPCooN4AFqgAIvQsBlIy0PJofDR%20lADmANwG6pr5BNBFZWRhFIjUtEiqAK7IlAASqJDgRJhMULAAdFzo-AAMOuWqqK2IHV29-UQAkpTgkvG8oJCUAJ6gTMwh5W2dPX0DMqNYiDgAonFJABRvkioAVgCUDAA%20TLCS4rG4bLY7DD8SQ6E6gb7lEK-cpNFrYaRVVAAYSWV02AwAHvDQdc1jgCVD0PdMbktKV2CBQLJEKBoIcAA4JSIPHDIGCSZqgFI4VAAQnC81o2SxAHksAAxWnpWAAJVs8JGkHGtkmAEYdPwZXS0LjlpQCahCUE0eglqhRjZim8AOTGvKoeVKnIqyDqzgulTurRe5X0f2-IA)

Comment: Please consider editing the code here to form a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/DWKezN) and demonstrating your issue.  Right now I don't quite know what `data` is, and even if I make a guess, I don't see how `data.rows[0].map(cb)` would produce anything but an array, which won't have a `firstName` property.

Comment: You seem to have something mixed up in your playground. Your data-rows are still objects, so there is no need to use an index to access their values.

At the last line of your code, you could just do this: `let firstNameOfFirstDataRow = data.rows[1].firstName`

Comment: @Lusito yes you are right, sorry, I've fixed it

Comment: Before we can even begin to address strongly typing `columnHeaderIndices` the way you want, you need to produce the right value in the first place.  Let's ignore TypeScript for the time being: in plain JavaScript, your `columnHeaderIndices` *is an array*. Use `console.log()` and [see for yourself](https://tsplay.dev/yNay0N); you are getting something like `[{Joe: 0}, {Blow: 1}]`, *not* `{Joe: 0, Blow: 1}` and *certainly* not `{firstName: 0, lastName: 1}`.  The point of a [mcve] is to clearly demonstrate an issue; right now I am still, unfortunately, confused, and can't proceed.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Fixed again

Comment: But `{Joe: 0, Blow: 1}` still does not have a `firstName` property, so I'm not sure why you expect `columnHeaderIndices.firstName` to be valid. I'm afraid I probably need to disengage with this question from now on, as my efforts to solicit a [mcve] have yet to bear fruit, which I assume is frustrating for both of us.  Perhaps someone else will be able to understand what you are trying to accomplish without such an example and be able to help you.  Sorry, and good luck again!

Comment: @jcalz so sorry! As you could see I accidentally duplicated the data row. arrggh, now it's how you expected. Hope you can reengage. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this (not sure).

from Typescript 2.1 you can use the type ***record***.

Usage:

```
interface TheData {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
}


type YourTypeName = Record<number, TheData>
// or inverted
type YourTypeName = Record<TheData, number>
// or to make things optional
type YourTypeName = Partial<Record<number, TheData>>
```

Comment: Gives me an error: `Type 'TheData' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAsIBE5jsgbwChlSZgoBnMAOTgFsIAuZaqUAcwG4TSAbONTqMWbTjwC+RImACeABxQBNAPYBXKKgURhEAIzIAvMgBKEBCqgATADwg19AEbQANGkw48APmkB6X8iWyKAAbtCQVjLayKoaWoq6AExGpuaWthjYuHBu9k7QPkT+gVDIYCrI9HAA1ihg6JyUgfJgwCogcHxRijHqmtq6AMwpAApwUK2dNmYW1nYOzlBumZ5wXl5AA

Answer (score 0):

With the latest code, you can either do this if you don't know the header names beforehand:

```
const columnHeaderIndices: Record<string, number> = {};
columnHeaders.forEach((i, j)=> {
   columnHeaderIndices[i] = j;
});
```

But this won't give you autocompletion on the possible header names.
Instead, you can do this if you do know the header names:

```
const columnHeaderIndices = {
   firstName: columnHeaders.indexOf("firstName"),
   lastName: columnHeaders.indexOf("lastName")
}
```

Comment: How will this get Typescript to know what properties are on `columnHeaderIndices`?

Comment: - In the second snippet, you told TypeScript what properties exist (left side of the colon). That's how TypeScript knows.

- In the first snippet, TypeScript will not know what properties exist. Because you don't know. If you don't know, TypeScript can't know.

TypeScript doesn't magically analyze your request and find out all properties in runtime. TypeScript is compile-time, so you'll have to know and tell TypeScript somehow.